# How can I use jQuery to automatically set unique alt tags for each image on page?

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use jQuery to automatically set an alt tag on images without one. My images are displayed on the page like this:

```
<div class="thumbinner">
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img alt="" src="#" class="thumbimage">
  </a>
  <div class="thumbcaption">Caption</div>
</div>
```

I've tried a couple of examples I've seen here on Stack Overflow, but I'm thoroughly confused on how to select the correct *.thumbcaption* text.

Any help would definitely be useful!

Comment: do you want to set the caption on  images inside thumbinner class ? or all the images? And what do you mean by unique alt tags?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? it is not clear on your quesiton

Comment: @karthick, I'm trying to set the alt tag only on the image inside the respective *thumbinner* class.

Comment: @SilentCoder, I have dozens of images on certain pages, all formatted using the code above. I am trying to set the image ALT text to the *.thumbcaption* text within the same *.thumbinner* div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to set the captions on all the images inside thumbinner.

```
$('.thumbinner').each(function(){
   var caption = $(this).find('.thumbcaption').text();
   $(this).find('img').attr('alt', caption);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.thumbinner').each(function(){
    let thumbcaption = $(this).find('.thumbcaption').text();
    $(this).find('img').attr('alt', thumbcaption);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbinner">
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img alt="" src="#" class="thumbimage">
  </a>
  <div class="thumbcaption">Caption</div>
</div>
```